# Boolean variable not being passed to getBoolean variable

Tags: android, bundle

```
Intent i = new Intent(AndroidGUIActivity.this, Basic_database_questionsActivity.class);
Bundle b = new Bundle();
// get the current value of timerStart variable and store it in timerlogic
Log.e(LOGS, "Whatis the value of timerstart inside the intentcalls method" +  timerStart);
b.getBoolean("timerlogic", timerStart);
boolean timermagic= b.getBoolean("timerlogic");
Log.e(LOGS, "Whatis the value of timerstart passed to timermagic" + timermagic);
```

I am not sure why timermagics variable has a value of false and not true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set a boolean using [`Bundle#putBoolean(String,boolean)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#putBoolean%28java.lang.String,%20boolean%29), so this:

```
b.getBoolean("timerlogic", timerStart);
```

Should be:

```
b.putBoolean("timerlogic", timerStart);
```